# Openpyxl merge is very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to merge existing excel's cells using `openpyxl` like below:

```
import datetime as dt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb[sheet_name]
start_row = 50000 #Hardcodig for example
end_row  = 100000
for index in range(start_row, end_row):
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=index, start_column=11, end_row=index, end_column=12) # Merging column 11 and 12
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Python takes one second to merge one row, took almost 10 mins to merge 700 rows. I've to merge the 50k records in real time.

How can I speed up this?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to merge so many rows? Yes, it's slow because of the checks that openpyxl does.

Comment: @CharlieClark The requirement is to pass values to excel, and excel has two column cells merged already for the existing data. So, have to merge before passing the cells to be consistent with the format.